# Write to file with adjusted (incremental) indentation in Fortran

Tags: fortran, indentation, fortran90

Having many nested subroutines in a `Fortran 90` program, I'd like to print the nesting level of these to a file with an indentation length proportional to the level (i.e., info printed in nested subroutines have higher indentation than calling ones).
Additional info including different datatypes would be written (strings, integers, ...).

I think about different ways to do that (in this example, `lev` is the level and is just built in a loop but it is otherwise updated in each subroutine):

```
Program adaptIndent

INTEGER :: lev 
CHARACTER (LEN=*), PARAMETER :: fmt1 = '(I1,'': ''A)'
CHARACTER (LEN=*), PARAMETER :: fmt2 = '(I2,'': ''A)'

DO lev=1,10
  CALL printindent1
  !CALL printindent2
  !CALL printindent3
ENDDO

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE printindent1 !convert everything (incl. indent and lev) to CHAR
  CHARACTER(LEN=lev) :: indent
  CHARACTER(LEN=2) :: strlev
  WRITE(indent, '(A)') ' '
  WRITE(strlev, '(I2)') lev
  WRITE(*, '(A)') indent//TRIM(ADJUSTL(strlev))//': this is my level'
END SUBROUTINE printindent1

SUBROUTINE printindent2 !build a new format defining the indentation
  CHARACTER(LEN=2) :: strlev
  CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: fmtlev
  WRITE(strlev, '(I2)') lev
  WRITE(fmtlev, '(A)') '('//TRIM(ADJUSTL(strlev))//'X, A)'
  WRITE(*, fmtlev) TRIM(ADJUSTL(strlev))//': this is my level'
END SUBROUTINE printindent2

SUBROUTINE printindent3 !add indent as CHAR to an existing format
  CHARACTER(LEN=lev) :: indent
  WRITE(indent, '(A)') ' '
  IF(lev.LT.10) THEN
    WRITE(*, fmt1(1:1)//'A,'//fmt1(2:)) indent, lev, 'this is my level'
  ELSE
    WRITE(*, fmt2(1:1)//'A,'//fmt2(2:)) indent, lev, 'this is my level'
  ENDIF  
END SUBROUTINE printindent3

END Program adaptIndent
```

The (desired) output is identical for these solutions:

```
 1: this is my level
  2: this is my level
   3: this is my level
    4: this is my level
     5: this is my level
      6: this is my level
       7: this is my level
        8: this is my level
         9: this is my level
          10: this is my level
```

My problem is that each time I do the useful `WRITE(*, *fmt*)`, I need preliminary (and ugly) steps to do that:

- compute an indent as a character and convert everything to CHAR in solution 1;
- define a new format with the appropriate number of leading blanks in solution 2;
- adapt existing format to include indent as CHAR in solution 3 (note the problem here is more: is there a way to define a unique format to write integers of any size without any trailing or leading blanks?)

Would there be any smarter solution to do that more elegantly than the many steps above?

Comment: You've tagged this as [tag:fortran90] - do you really need an answer that strictly conforms to that (very old) standard rather than something newer?

Comment: @francescalus: given the program I use (dozens of thousands of lines) is entirely written in f90, yes I'd be happy to have a solution fully compatible with this standard. But why - did you think about a non-f90 solution? I'd be happy to learn that, too :)

Comment: There's the `I0` feature (not F90), but in addition to general good-practice (don't tag with a language revision tag if that's not a requirement), I'd have thoughts around what you'd want to happen around things like splitting lines sharing a common indentation.  Handling those may be much easier, say, with allocatable temporary things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the intrinsic [`REPEAT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/REPEAT.html#REPEAT)

and write something like:

```
write(*,"(A,I0,A)")repeat(" ",lev),lev, str
```

Comment: Thanks @Edmondo Giovannozzi, this is a simple and efficient way to do that, which I didn't think about. Works very nice!

Answer (score 2):

If you assign a string to a character that is shorter than that character length, it gets padded with spaces. You can use that to create an indent character with the appropriate length easily.

Plus, all compilers I use understand the `I0` format descriptor, which means: Use exactly as many characters as needed.

Here's my idea:

```
program printindent_test
    implicit none
    integer :: i
    character(len=20) :: s
    do i = 1, 10
        call printindent("This is my level", i)
    end do
contains
    subroutine printindent(str, lev)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: str
        integer, intent(in) :: lev
        character(len=lev) :: indent
        indent = ''
        write(*, '(A, I0, ": ", A)') indent, lev, str
    end subroutine printindent
end program printindent_test
```

You don't have to do quite so many conversions to get the format string either.

```
write(fmtlev, "('('I2'X,I0,A)')") lev
write(*, fmtlev) lev, ": this is my level"
```

will work just as fine.

If your compiler doesn't understand the `I0` format, you can manually do something like this:

```
write(to_write, '(I2, ": ", A)') lev, str
write(*, '(2A)') indent, TRIM(ADJUSTL(to_write))
```

Of course you'd have to create a new temporary character variable of appropriate size:

```
character(len=4+LEN_TRIM(str)) :: to_write
```

Comment: Thanks @chw21, this is all very useful information for me. Edmondo's answer is very simple and efficient, but your detailed comments really helped me!